# Rails - NoMethodError - undefined method 'scoped' for AccessToFinance:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, rails-activerecord

So i am getting this error `NoMethodError - undefined method 'scoped' for AccessToFinance:Module:` and i have read up a ton since about 1pm and i cant figure out whats wrong.

The work flow of this story looks like the following.

`app/models/scorecards/alpha/financial_generic_alpha_scorecard.rb`

```
class FinancialGenericAlphaScorecard < GenericAlphaScorecard
  has_one :access_to_finance, :foreign_key => :scorecard_id 
  has_one :appropriate_product, :through => :access_to_finance
  has_one :insurance_policy, :through => :access_to_finance

end
```

`app/models/access_to_finance.rb`

```
class AccessToFinance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :scorecard
  has_one :appropriate_product
  has_one :insurance_policy
end
```

`app/models/appropriate_product.rb`

```
class AppropriateProduct < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :access_to_finance
end
```

`app/models/insurance_policy.rb`

```
class InsurancePolicy < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :access_to_finance
end
```

within the routes file

```
resource :access_to_finance, :controller => 'access_to_finance' do
  resources :appropriate_products
  resources :insurance_policies
end
```

the controllers are named

`app/controllers/access_to_finance_controller.rb`

```
class AccessToFinanceController < ElementController
end
```

`app/controllers/appropriate_products_controller.rb`

```
class AppropriateProductsController < ElementController
end
```

`app/controllers/insurance_policies_controller.rb`

```
class InsurancePoliciesController < ElementController
end
```

As far as i can tell everything is named correctly because its all 1-1 relations. so there is no need to pluralize anything?? i think i am going to go crazy.

**Update**

so i tried some more crazy things. and my senior came over to help me. and in the digging we found that when the access_to_finance.rb model is in an folder then it gets dropped out the load path we have this bit of code to add dynamic folders to the load path.

```
 Dir.glob("#{Rails.root}/app/models/*[^(.rb|.ignore)]").each {|dir| config.autoload_paths << dir }
```

But somehow a file that hasn't been committed gets `.ignore` on it why this is? is beyond me  we removed the .ignore and commit the file and it found the model and it worked. so i am still sitting here like what the heck just happened

hope this helpes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when you specify a foreign key in a model like you did here

```
has_one :access_to_finance, :foreign_key => :scorecard_id
```

You also have to specify the Class like this

```
has_one :access_to_finance, :foreign_key => :scorecard_id, :class_name => :AccessToFinance
```

Comment: Nope it still wasnt being found basically the file wasnt being loaded at all. but it is very good to be specific in your calls like that. so plus one to good coding.